# android - blank space appear at the top

Tags: android, tabbar

In my app, I use the tab bar. Sometimes a blank space appear at the top. How to resolve this?

please, can anybody help me?

**Tab bar code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" 
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#000" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5px"/>            
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Contactus**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:orientation="vertical">


<!-- Title for ContactUs screen -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_contactus_Title" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CU_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                        
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"                
            android:text="@string/ContactUS_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>   

 <ScrollView 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">     
     <LinearLayout  
            android:id="@+id/LL_Contactus_SV" 
            android:orientation="vertical"              
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <!-- General Information -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_generalinfo_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_generalinfo_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/General_info"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_generalmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/General_info_email"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"      
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"                 
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Suggestions -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_sugesstionsinfo_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_sugesstionsinfo_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Suggestions"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_suggestionsmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Suggestions_email"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Billing -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_billing_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_billing_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Billing_ques"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_billingmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Billing_email"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Technical -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_technical_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_technical_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Tech_ques"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_techmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Tech_email"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Account-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_account_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_account_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/General_account_ques"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_accountmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/General_account_email"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Reports -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_report_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_report_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Report_info"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_reportmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Report_email"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Special Projects -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_sprojects_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_sprojects_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/special_projects"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_sprojectsmail_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/special_projects_email"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>                               
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Phone -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/CU_Phone_LL" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CU_phoneinfo_tv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                            android:text="@string/Phone_info"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CU_phoneno_tv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                            android:text="@string/Phone_number"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>   
                    </LinearLayout>                     

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CU_timings_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                    
                        android:text="@string/Timings"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>                            
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>               

</LinearLayout>
```

**Original Image**

[image]

**Problem Image**

[image]

Comment: are both images from an actual device?

Comment: no i took from emulator. is any problem?but i face the same issue in device also

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem in your xml

you can do something by

setting imageview(Contact us) margingTop = 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put scroll bar on Tab Bar not on the context of the tab bar... Check that first

Comment: How to differentiate this?means how to identify this?

Comment: Post the xml of your layout I ll show you How??? You must put scroll view tag after Tab bar tag.